# How can I stop a UISearchDisplayController from updating as I type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I stop a UISearchDisplayController from updating as I type? numberOfRowsInSection gets called many times as the user types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `UISearchBar`'s delegate to your view controller, and then only forward some messages to the `UISearchDisplayController`.